# Post method sending to next page

Tags: php, html

how do I send a get query string to the next page? I know the format for what the query string should be I just don't understand the actual process of redirecting to the next page.

instead of something like an `href` but one that you don't have to click on for it to send the query string to the next page.

```
<?php 

///receiving from page1 and storing as variable
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];  

//quarry string with firstname and lastname
    page3.php?firstname=<?php echo $firstname;?>&lastname=<?php echo $lastname;?>
```

Comment: the only thing i can think of is an href but i don't want an actual submit button that links

Comment: if you are using form then use `method = "get"` or share your code

Comment: well im not using form im taking in POST data from another page as a variable hold on ill post what i have. im wondering if there is anyway to not have a submission button like on a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well technically there are 2 available options you could use. Whether or not you should use them is a different story.

**GET Request**

A get request would involve the same original form, but instead of `method="post"`, you would do this; `method="get"`. What this does is add all the form data to the specified action url as a query string.

To then get the data, it's very much like the way you get `POST` data.

`$varName = $_GET['name']`, where name is the name specified in your form.

This way is nice because it means you don't have to process `POST` data before then auto sending it off to another page.

**POST Request**

Your existing code is currently using a `POST` request, which does make sense in some situations, such as altering it before sending it off via a `GET`.

Though if you are going to use this method, this is what you need to do.

`header("location: $url");`, where `$url` is the variable of your `GET` request you're wanting to send off.

**TL;DR**

You should probably be using a `GET` request instead of a `POST` request, however it's still achievable.

just do it something like this;

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname'])) {
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        $state = $_POST['state'];
        $age = $_POST['age'];

        $url = "page3.php?firstname=".$firstname."&lastname=".$lastname;
        header("location: $url");
    }
?>
```